# python shell add_option problems

Tags: python, linux

I got some confusion in the python add_option

I write the code like this

```
parser.add_option("-u", "--uniqueness",
              action="store_true", dest="uniqueness", default=False)
```

Later in the shell, I want to write something like:

```
if(the user input -u option):
     do something
```

My question is, how can I write "the user input -u option" in python? I tried to use "if(parser.uniqueness)" however, this command doesn't work. Btw I am using python 2.7.3 (just wonder if this command will be different from the command in python 3) thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `optparse` is deprecated, so you should use `argparse` - but the logic will be similar.

You need to do `args = parser.parse_args()` somewhere first, and then check in this object with :

```
if args.uniqueness:
  # potato
```

Comment: is there any different between args = parser.parse_args() and option,args = parser.parse_args()?

Comment: The first usage you have is for argparse and the second for optparse.  Prefer to change your code to use argparse if you can.